# How to draw vertex function Feynman diagram

Tags: tikz-feynman, feynmp-auto, feynmp

[image]
I would like to draw the following Feynman diagram in LaTeX (Overleaf). I don't have any back ground with packages such as `tikz-feynman` or `tikz` etc...

Please help me to draw the following diagram.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please add a MWE of your current attempt. At the moment this is just a "Do it for me" question.

Comment: You have already asked [4 questions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A220278+%5Btikz-feynman%5D) about the same `tikz-feynman` package. What is it that you do not understand in the answers given to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtained your drawing using Mathcha https://www.mathcha.io/editor... if you have no experience with the packages that you have mentioned.

[image]

```
%% Compile and read me!
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}} %set default line width to 0.75pt        

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
%uncomment if require: \path (0,419); %set diagram left start at 0, and has height of 419

%Shape: Wave [id:dp86152123318] 
\draw   (213.52,105.48) .. controls (217.6,109.82) and (221.51,113.95) .. (226.03,113.94) .. controls (230.56,113.94) and (234.45,109.79) .. (238.52,105.44) .. controls (242.58,101.08) and (246.48,96.94) .. (251,96.93) .. controls (255.52,96.92) and (259.43,101.05) .. (263.52,105.39) .. controls (267.6,109.73) and (271.51,113.86) .. (276.03,113.85) .. controls (280.56,113.84) and (284.45,109.69) .. (288.52,105.34) .. controls (292.58,100.99) and (296.48,96.84) .. (301,96.83) .. controls (305.52,96.82) and (309.43,100.95) .. (313.52,105.29) .. controls (317.6,109.63) and (321.51,113.76) .. (326.03,113.75) .. controls (330.56,113.74) and (334.45,109.6) .. (338.52,105.24) .. controls (342.58,100.89) and (346.48,96.74) .. (351,96.74) .. controls (355.52,96.73) and (359.43,100.86) .. (363.52,105.2) .. controls (367.6,109.54) and (371.51,113.67) .. (376.03,113.66) .. controls (377.95,113.65) and (379.76,112.9) .. (381.51,111.71) ;
%Straight Lines [id:da27216730598644623] 
\draw    (174,56) -- (306.5,222) ;
%Straight Lines [id:da8990246920217928] 
\draw    (413.5,63) -- (306.5,222) ;
%Shape: Triangle [id:dp5517190725607068] 
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (203.12,91.77) -- (180.2,80) -- (195.78,67.07) -- cycle ;
%Straight Lines [id:da14648823506129793] 
\draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 80; green, 227; blue, 194 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]    (204,48) -- (230.7,83.6) ;
\draw [shift={(232.5,86)}, rotate = 233.13] [color={rgb, 255:red, 80; green, 227; blue, 194 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]    (14.21,-6.37) .. controls (9.04,-2.99) and (4.3,-0.87) .. (0,0) .. controls (4.3,0.87) and (9.04,2.99) .. (14.21,6.37)   ;
%Shape: Triangle [id:dp7176971853762271] 
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (251.69,152.8) -- (274.99,163.78) -- (259.85,177.23) -- cycle ;
%Straight Lines [id:da9552502312459754] 
\draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 80; green, 227; blue, 194 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]    (260,85) -- (331.5,84.04) ;
\draw [shift={(334.5,84)}, rotate = 539.23] [color={rgb, 255:red, 80; green, 227; blue, 194 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]    (14.21,-6.37) .. controls (9.04,-2.99) and (4.3,-0.87) .. (0,0) .. controls (4.3,0.87) and (9.04,2.99) .. (14.21,6.37)   ;
%Straight Lines [id:da375958037424136] 
\draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 80; green, 227; blue, 194 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]    (372,85) -- (395.83,49.49) ;
\draw [shift={(397.5,47)}, rotate = 483.86] [color={rgb, 255:red, 80; green, 227; blue, 194 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]    (14.21,-6.37) .. controls (9.04,-2.99) and (4.3,-0.87) .. (0,0) .. controls (4.3,0.87) and (9.04,2.99) .. (14.21,6.37)   ;
%Shape: Triangle [id:dp07412158877594588] 
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (405.4,74.99) -- (399.97,100.17) -- (383.44,88.47) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Triangle [id:dp8166568288348335] 
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (333.55,180.21) -- (339.39,155.12) -- (355.72,167.09) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Wave [id:dp9476756301086628] 
\draw   (307.49,221.51) .. controls (300.83,225.58) and (294.49,229.48) .. (294.49,234.01) .. controls (294.49,238.53) and (300.83,242.43) .. (307.49,246.51) .. controls (314.15,250.58) and (320.49,254.48) .. (320.49,259.01) .. controls (320.49,263.53) and (314.15,267.43) .. (307.49,271.51) .. controls (300.83,275.58) and (294.49,279.48) .. (294.49,284.01) .. controls (294.49,288.53) and (300.83,292.43) .. (307.49,296.51) .. controls (314.15,300.58) and (320.49,304.48) .. (320.49,309.01) .. controls (320.49,313.53) and (314.15,317.43) .. (307.49,321.51) .. controls (300.83,325.58) and (294.49,329.48) .. (294.49,334.01) .. controls (294.49,337.6) and (298.49,340.79) .. (303.47,344) ;
%Straight Lines [id:da5308331624006375] 
\draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 80; green, 227; blue, 194 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]    (263,216) -- (228.42,174.31) ;
\draw [shift={(226.5,172)}, rotate = 410.32] [color={rgb, 255:red, 80; green, 227; blue, 194 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]    (14.21,-6.37) .. controls (9.04,-2.99) and (4.3,-0.87) .. (0,0) .. controls (4.3,0.87) and (9.04,2.99) .. (14.21,6.37)   ;
%Straight Lines [id:da4752000077572216] 
\draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 80; green, 227; blue, 194 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]    (377,176) -- (352.22,211.54) ;
\draw [shift={(350.5,214)}, rotate = 304.89] [color={rgb, 255:red, 80; green, 227; blue, 194 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]    (14.21,-6.37) .. controls (9.04,-2.99) and (4.3,-0.87) .. (0,0) .. controls (4.3,0.87) and (9.04,2.99) .. (14.21,6.37)   ;
%Straight Lines [id:da03259324569884825] 
\draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 80; green, 227; blue, 194 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]    (273.5,312) -- (273.5,252) ;
\draw [shift={(273.5,249)}, rotate = 450] [color={rgb, 255:red, 80; green, 227; blue, 194 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]    (14.21,-6.37) .. controls (9.04,-2.99) and (4.3,-0.87) .. (0,0) .. controls (4.3,0.87) and (9.04,2.99) .. (14.21,6.37)   ;

% Text Node
\draw (249,272.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$k$};
% Text Node
\draw (227,196.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$q$};
% Text Node
\draw (382,189.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$q-k$};
% Text Node
\draw (218,34.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$p$};
% Text Node
\draw (340,37.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$p+k$};
% Text Node
\draw (276,59.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$p+q$};


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```